# MySql count occurrences of failure codes

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to count the number of times something happened with a failure status in my database and retrieve the name of the failure. I have a table `builds` that holds what the `failurearea` is and table called `failureareas` that has the names of all the failurearea codes. I want to be able to count these so I can graph out the data and tell our devs how their builds most commonly fail.

This is what I am trying, but it isn't working:

```
SELECT COUNT(B.id), F.name 
   FROM builds B 
  JOIN failureareas F ON B.failurearea = F.id
 WHERE DATE(B.submittime) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
   AND B.buildstatus != 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(B.id), F.name
FROM builds B  JOIN failureareas F ON B.failurearea = F.id
WHERE DATE(B.submittime) >=  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND B.buildstatus != 2
GROUP BY F.name
```

Comment: dur, I always forget to use GROUP BY, Thanks!

Comment: +1: If the `GROUP BY` is omitted, in the OP's example [MySQL's "hidden column" functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) is being used